# Python regex. * doesn't work for second match

Tags: python, regex, python-re

As far as I know, * means in regex match more than 0 occurrence.
And {n,m} means equal or more than n occurrence and equal or less than m occurrence.

But the below code is something strange.
What I want to do is find numbers.

```
0 >>> import re
1 >>> 
2 >>> re.search(r'[a-z]{4,6}[0-9]{2,6}', 'bird99')
3 <re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='bird99'>
4 >>> re.search(r'[0-9]{2,6}', 'bird99')
5 <re.Match object; span=(4, 6), match='99'>
6 >>> re.search(r'[0-9]{0,6}', 'bird99')
7 <re.Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
8 >>> re.search(r'[0-9]*', 'bird99')
9 <re.Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
```

I expect match for 99 on result line number 7 and 9, but it doesn't make any match.
Anybody can explain this result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to match **0** or more digits, so this matches perfectly with the empty string at the start of your string.

Comment: Note that the `span(0,0)` clearly shows the match is at position zero and with length zero.

Comment: It means that * can match every string because any string contains 0 occurrence of any pattern right?

Answer (score 1):

`r[0-9]*` matches **zero or more** ASCII digits.  `re.search` finds the *first* match, which is zero digits.  Compare the result for `re.findall`:

```
>>> re.search(r'[0-9]*', 'bird99')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
>>> re.findall(r'[0-9]*', 'bird99')
['', '', '', '', '99', '']
```